# How to append ind HTML table with php?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a simple Point of sale using PHP, and I want to add data in my table everytime I search and submit the barcode. The problem with my code, it only runs once, it appends the first data I add but for the next nothing happens, here is my HTML

```
<form class="" action="" id="pos_data" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="txtSearch"  placeholder="barcode" autofocus>
</form>

<table id="pos-items">
    <thead><tr>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Unit</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and this my script

```
$('#pos_data').submit(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'processpos.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(newContent) {
    $('#pos-items tbody').append(newContent);
          }
    });
return false;
barcodeenter();
});

function barcodeenter(){

document.querySelector('#txtSearch').addEventListener('keypress', function (e){
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key === 13) { // 13 is enter
      console.log(document.getElementById("txtSearch").value);
      document.getElementById("txtSearch").value = "";

    }
    });
}
```

and my PHP file

```
include 'conn_db.php';
$product_id = $_POST['txtSearch'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM producttbl WHERE product_id ='".$product_id."'";
$records = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);



while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

    echo "<tr><td>".$row['product_name']."</td><td>1</td><td>".$row['product_unit']."</td><td>".$row['product_price']."</td></tr>";
}
```

all in the code works for the first product but when i try to add another nothing happens. Is there anything I'm missing out here?

Comment: Can you check the console, what is the value returned in the second  attempt ?

Comment: that what i don't know? but as I understand the .append would it just add the returned value to the table?

Comment: There is a tool in your browser called a console, you can access it by Right click > Inspect element > choose the console tab.
Then try to post the product and see what happens

Comment: It displays the product id that was entered..

Comment: Doesn't it show what the php file returned ?

Comment: hi the just found my error, i have a function that I call inside success function, that will clear the text field...my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the function barcodeenter()

and replace with `document.getElementById("pos_data").reset();`

```
 $('#pos_data').submit(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'processpos.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(newContent) {
                        $('#pos-items tbody').append(newContent);
                    }
                });
                //barcodeenter();
                document.getElementById("pos_data").reset();
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I encountered the same issue a long time ago,
what i did was,
instead of returning html tags as response,
make it return json data, it solved my problem,


$.ajax({
    url: 'processpos.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: id,
    success: function(newContent) {
              $.each(response, function(a,b){  
                $('#pos-items tbody').append("<tr><td>"+b.field+"</td></tr>");
              }) 
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Change

```
 $rowdata ='';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

    $rowdata .= "<tr><td>".$row['product_name']."</td><td>1</td>   <td>".$row['product_unit']."</td><td>".$row['product_price']."</td></tr>";
    }

echo json_encode($rowdata);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

    echo "<tr><td>".$row['product_name']."</td><td>1</td><td>".$row['product_unit']."</td><td>".$row['product_price']."</td></tr>";
}
```

To

```
    $rowdata ='';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

    $rowdata .= "<tr><td>".$row['product_name']."</td><td>1</td>   <td>".$row['product_unit']."</td><td>".$row['product_price']."</td></tr>";
}

echo $rowdata;
```

Comment: It's the same !

Comment: @mehdi bounya yes but its better to store the result in a variable and echo or return outside of the loop.

Comment: I don't really know if it's better, but it doesn't answer the problem

Comment: it might be breaking the loop with first echo that's why it's not appending other rows.